# ReferenceError: google is not defined using ng-map GeoCoder service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm getting the following error trying to use the geocoder service for the [ng-map library](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps):

`angular.js:13642 ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at Object.t [as geocode] (http://localhost:6240/Scripts/ng-map.min.js:25:28246)`

I'm injecting the service into my controller

```
appModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'NgMap', 'NavigatorGeolocation', 'GeoCoder', 
    function ($scope, NgMap, NavigatorGeolocation, GeoCoder) {
        GeoCoder.geocode({address: 'Avenida Calle 26 # 40-40, Bogotá'}).then(function (result) {
            //... do something with result
            console.log('RESULT GEOCODER: ', result);
        });
    }]);
```

I also tested it with NgMap function getting the same reference error

```
NgMap.getGeoLocation('Avenida Calle 26 # 40-40, Bogotá').then(function (result) {
    console.log('GETGEOLOCATION: ', result);
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error getting geolocation: ', error);
});
```

As shown in the snippet, I have successfully used other NgMap and NavigatorGeolocation services.

Here is the code of my page

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-lazy-load-params="{{ $ctrl.googleMapsUrl }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ng-map id="map"
                center="{{ $ctrl.mapCenter }}"
                street-view="{{ $ctrl.svp }}"></ng-map>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ng-map id="sv" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in the corresponding controller/component

```
$ctrl.googleMapsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY";
$ctrl.mapCenter = 'current-location';

NavigatorGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({ timeout: 10000 }).then(function (ll) {
    $ctrl.svp = "StreetViewPanorama(document.querySelector('ng-map#sv'), {position:new google.maps.LatLng(" + ll.coords.latitude + " , " + ll.coords.longitude + ")})";
 }, function (error) {
     console.log('error getCurrentPosition: ', error);
 });
```

I'm using AngularJS v1.5.6

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GeoCoder` service utilizes `google.maps.Geocoder class` which in turn is a part of Google Maps API. The moment when `GeoCoder.geocode` method is invoked in controller Google Maps library is not yet loaded (in your case it is loaded *asynchronously* via `map-lazy-load` directive), that's the reason why this error occurs.

You could use `NgMap.getMap` function to guarantee Google Maps API is ready:

```
NgMap.getMap("map").then(function () {

      GeoCoder.geocode({ address: 'Avenida Calle 26 # 40-40, Bogotá' })
      .then(function (result) {
            //...
      });

 });
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', 'NgMap', 'NavigatorGeolocation', 'GeoCoder',
        function ($scope, NgMap, NavigatorGeolocation, GeoCoder) {
            vm = this;

            NgMap.getMap("map").then(function () {

                GeoCoder.geocode({ address: 'Avenida Calle 26 # 40-40, Bogotá' })
                    .then(function (result) {
                        vm.mapCenter = result[0].geometry.location;
                    });

            });


            vm.googleMapsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js";
            vm.mapCenter = null;


        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl as vm">

  <div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-lazy-load-params="{{ vm.googleMapsUrl }}">
   <ng-map id="map" center="{{ vm.mapCenter }}"></ng-map>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect Vadim, It worked enclosing it with the getMap promise. Thanks!

Comment: This no longer works, as an API key is required.  Does anyone know of a complete, standalone example?